# Parsing between quotes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

I'm trying to parse a string, but I'm running into trouble:

`str = " @Var(\"^This is the text I want to save.\") "`

What I want to parse out is: `^This is the text I want to save.` Basically anything that's between the quotes.

I was trying to use a `str.split()`... but I'm unsure about what to specify.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex. Here:

```
puts str.scan(/"(.*)"/)[0][0]
# ^This is the text I want to save.
```

The above regex basically looks for everything that is between `"` and `"` and returns them.

Comment: That's close, but not quite. Between the *quotes*, not the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

This should work - assuming you don't expect there to be multiple quoted sections. The 1 specifies the match group you want.

```
puts str[/"(.*)"/, 1]                                            
# ^This is the text I want to save.
```

Comment: It's simple enough to change the `.` to `[^"]` to account for multiple quotes. Also you don't need to escape `"` in regex.

Comment: Yes, very good point @Joshua - I was just thinking about that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get array of arrays of different size, you may do it in two steps: `.split` and `.scan`. In your case `.scan` has `()` on two sides of `|`, that's why you have trouble with nil (Which supposed to be useful, but not it your case). So you have either use `.flatten.compact` or add the 3rd step of `.delete`.

Try this:

```
text.split("\n").map{|i|p i.scan(/'([^']+)'|(\w+)/).flatten.compact}
text.split("\n").map{|i|p i.scan(/'[^']+'|\w+/).map{|i|i.delete "'"}}
```